# Why does this problem appear in the model and what is the solution to it is very necessary?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: this is my model]

[image: this my problem]

I have the problem in my project in my model spitioal and I need fix it in soon time ,please.

Comment: Don't put images of code. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this site](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=dart) for create your model